# Updated system and Firefox now won't let me type tildes or backquotes

Tags: 12.04, firefox, keyboard

```
% uname -a
Linux phoebe 3.2.0-33-generic #52-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 18 16:29:15 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'm running 12.04 on the machine I'm typing this on, and I've been running it for quite some time.  I just did a dist-upgrade, and it included some update for Firefox (to 17.0.1 now).  After restarting the browser, I noted with some surprise that I can't type back-quotes or tildes.  They worked just a few minutes ago before the update, but not now.

I use a Deck keyboad, and I have the back-quote/tilde key remapped. I've had the keyboard for many years now and the remapping has always worked:

```
% xmodmap -pk | egrep tilde
133         0x0060 (grave)  0x007e (asciitilde)     0x0060 (grave)  0x007e (asciitilde)
```

I can type those characters into xterm windows, into Chrome, gvim, gedit, etc.  What in the world is going on with Firefox?  I can't find any relevant configuration options, and I certainly haven't been tinkering with them.  I've tried restarting it a couple times too.

I'll try running a new clean profile and see if that makes a difference; I do have some add-ons but nothing new and nothing particularly crazy. *edit* Nope, can't type the characters in a plain-jane profile either.

*edit* — reinstalled Firefox, same thing.

*edit again* — I've also found that VirtualBox seems to ignore the xmodmap remapping.  I've basically got the grave/tilde key swapped with another key that's remapped to "Alt".  In VirtualBox now (I don't think it was always this way, but I'm not 100% sure), I can type back-quote or tilde with the key that's swapped to "Alt".  However, that does not work in Firefox — neither key works as the grave/tilde key, though I've just verified that the remapped "Alt" key in Firefox does work (as "Alt")!!

*edit yet again* — upgraded to 12.10, same problem. *Something* changed *somewhere*, as I am 100% positive that that key was working today and over the past many months. (Why? How do you quote code snippets inline in Markdown? I'm on Stackoverflow *a lot* and that's how I noticed it was broken.)

Comment: You may have something wrong with the update as if you just made a `dist-update`, `uname` is not reflecting it. Should be `3.2.0-35-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 5 17:42:16 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`. (Not that I think this can be the issue with the keyboard). Is your keyboard configured as `US`? No dead-keys? How are the other accent keys working? `'`, `^`?

Comment: @laurent yes I picked up the new kernel but I haven't rebooted yet :-)  The keyboard is a US keyboard, and right this very minute I can open an xterm and type all the tilde characters I want. I can't type them here through Firefox however :(

Comment: Maybe you should only reboot then :)

Comment: @laurent yes I'm about to try that but I have very low expectations that it'll make a difference. I mean, the keyboard works fine on every other application in the system.

Comment: Yes but you upgraded a kernel and your machine isn't using it and firefox was upgraded after that possibly loading the parts it needs from the new libs. those thing can be very complex! :)

Comment: @laurent understood; Chrome was updated too.  I've rebooted now and it still doesn't work.  It's really odd.  I also noticed that VirtualBox also has issues with that key.

Comment: @laurent thanks for your help - I fixed the issue and I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My old (and I mean **old**) xmodmap remapping file included these two key lines:

```
keycode 49 = Alt_L
keycode 133 = grave asciitilde
```

Those two lines accomplished the remapping **only partially**.  What I had failed to do was this:

```
add mod1 = Alt_L
remove mod4 = Super_L
```

The key that I wanted to be the accent/tilde key had been a modifier key, for "mod4", with the keysym "Super_L". For some reason, that didn't start causing a problem until yesterday. Here I am in `Firefox` typing back-quotes just like before!!

So the bottom line is this: if you remap key symbols, make sure to check the modifier map. You can check the initial state of keys by starting a fresh X session and then typing:

```
xmodmap -pk
```

Then, view the initial modifier map with:

```
xmodmap
```

If you change keysyms for keycodes, make sure you add/remove them from the modifier map as necessary.

*edit* — oh also you can use `xev` to figure out what the keycode/keysym for a particular key is. Just run it from a terminal window; it's kind-of a mess but just mouse over its little window and press the key a couple times. Use `^C` (control-C) in the terminal window to stop it, or I guess the "Close" thingy on the window.